# Cannot read property 'get' of undefined. Using nodejs on Cloud9

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack, typeerror, cloud9

If this helps at all: I am following the instructions in chapter 3 of Simon Holmes' book, "Getting MEAN with Mongo, Express, Angular, and Node".

I am in the beginning stages of separating my routes and controllers into separate files. When I bypass creating the variables and hard code `require('express').Router().get('/', ctrlMain.index);` and other combinations that have the same functionality, I get the same error. So, I have narrowed the problem down to the first line of `index.js`, although the error I am getting points to the GET method in line 6 of the same file. I have provided my `index.js`, `main,js`, `app.js`, files, as well as the full error message I'm getting below. I would be happy to provide any other parts of my project/file structure if this information isn't enough! Hopefully someone will be able to point me in the right direction.

This is my `index.js` file:

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var ctrlMain = require('../controllers/main');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', ctrlMain.index);

module.exports = router;
```

My `main.js` file:

```js
/* GET home page */
module.exports.index = function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
};
```

and my `app.js` file (not sure if this is helpful):

```js
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./app_server/routes/index')
  , user = require('./app_server/routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/app_server' + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Finally, here is the error I'm getting:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/lab5/app_server/routes/index.js:6:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/lab5/app.js:6:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)`

Comment: This seems to be alright, so try to debug smarter. First, check the '../' notations. Make sure that it's finding the file properly (./ and ../ are common errors). Second, try removing the controllers and routes and try making the API routes within app.js itself. If that works, then create modules for routes and check. If that works, then create the module for controllers. You'll understand where it's going wrong.